# Tool in UNIX to subtract dates

Tags: shell, solaris, awk, utilities, date

Is there any tool in Solaris UNIX (so no GNU tool available) to subtract dates? I know that in Linux we have `gawk` that can subtract one date from another. But in Solaris the maximum we have is `nawk` (improved `awk`) which cannot perform date calculations. Also I cannot use perl.

Is there any way to do date calculations like `20100909 - 20001010`?

UPDATE: Is `bc` able to perform dates calculations?

Comment: See also [Quickly calculate date differences](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24626), for when GNU date is available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an awk script I just wrote up, should work with an POSIX awk.  You'll have to try the Solaris version; remember that there are two versions of Awk on Solaris as well, one in /bin and one in /usr/xpg4/bin/awk (which is nawk, I believe).

```
BEGIN {
    daysofmonth["01"] = 0; daysofmonth["02"] = 31; daysofmonth["03"] = 59;
    daysofmonth["04"] = 90; daysofmonth["05"] = 120; daysofmonth["06"] = 151;
    daysofmonth["07"] = 181; daysofmonth["08"] = 212; daysofmonth["09"] = 243;
    daysofmonth["10"] = 273; daysofmonth["11"] = 304; daysofmonth["12"] = 334;
    fullday = 86400;
}
/[12][09][0-9][0-9][01][0-9][0123][0-9]/ {
    year = substr($0, 1, 4); month = substr($0, 5, 2); day = substr($0, 7, 2);
    date = ((year - 1970) * 365.25) + daysofmonth[month] + day - 1;
    if ((year % 4) == 0 && month > 2) { date = date + 1; }
    print date * fullday - (25200);
}
{}
```

Pass a YYYYmmdd date string through and it will be converted to number of seconds since the Epoch (with a bit of give for being on day boundaries).  Then you will be able to subtract the two.

```
today=`echo 20110210 | awk -f convdate.awk`
then=`echo 20001231 | awk -f convdate.awk`
sincethen=`expr $today - $then`
```

Comment: I checked your logic with Oracle. For some dates is ok, however for it generates a float number. I'm afraid I have to truncate to an integer number, is it?

Comment: The decimal is the fraction of a second and not necessarily needed.

Comment: The epoch expires 20380119. Why not use the Julian day of year? Dupe... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302266/unix-non-posix-day-of-year-from-supplied-date

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, none of the POSIX command line utilities provide arithmetic on dates. `date -d` and `date +%s` are the way to go if you have them, but they're GNU extensions.

There's a clumsy hack with `touch` that sort of works for checking that a date is at least n days in the past:

```
touch -t 201009090000 stamp
if [ -n "$(find stamp -mtime +42)" ]; then ...
```

(Note that this code may be off by one if DST started or stopped in the interval and the script runs before 1am.)

Several people have ended up implementing date manipulation libraries in Bourne or POSIX shell. There are a few examples and links in the [comp.unix.shell FAQ](http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq.html#Q6).

Installing GNU tools may be the way of least pain.

Answer (score 12):

I would try using the `date` command which is part of POSIX so it is just about everywhere. **UPDATE: Unfortunately, it seems that -d is not part of POSIX date and likely not there on Solaris.  Thus this likely won't answer the OPs question.**

```
d1=`date -d 20100909 +%s`
d2=`date -d 20001010 +%s`
```

Now `d1` and `d2` are integers that correspond to seconds since the unix epoch.  Thus to get the difference between the two, we subtract( `$((d1-d2))` in bash) and covert to whatever units we want.  Days are the easiest:

```
echo "$(((d1-d2)/86400)) days"
```

How to do the conversion will likely be different if you don't have bash.  The most portable way may be to use `expr` ([expr's posix man page](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html)).

Comment: yeah this does not answer my question because it's Solaris... but thank you for the ideia and posting :)

Answer (score 8):

For the record, [dateutils](http://hroptatyr.github.com/dateutils) is my attempt at providing a set of portable tools that cover date arithmetics.  Your example boils down to

```
ddiff -i '%Y%m%d' 20001010 20100909
=>
  3621
```

The `-i` specifies the input format.

Comment: This package is awesome, and it exists in the Ubuntu universe libraries (at least for Trusty). On another system, I could compile it easily from scratch. Highly recommended. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also packaged in Fedora and in EPEL, for the RH ecosystem.

Answer (score 4):

Perl is likely to be installed, and it's easy enough to grab modules from [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/), install them in your home directory, and [refer to them](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) in your program.  In this case, the [Date::Calc](http://search.cpan.org/~stbey/Date-Calc-6.3/lib/Date/Calc.pod) module has a `Delta_Days` subroutine that will help.

Answer (score 3):

python:

```
 from datetime import datetime as dt
 a = dt(2010, 9, 9)
 b = dt(2000, 10, 10)
 print ( (a - b).days )
 3621
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrt GNU date on Solaris:

I say this again:

Too many Solaris SysAdmins take pride in deliberately not installing the official packages from Sun (now Oracle) that make a Solaris system "GNU compatible" when they configure a new host. Beats me why.

GNU Date is excellent and should be available by default on any Solaris host, IMHO.

### On Solaris 10

Install package SFWcoreu from the Solaris Companion CD. After install you will find GNU date in `/opt/sfw/bin/date`

### On Solaris 11

You may already have it as I believe it is part of the standard install. It is however called `gdate` in order to distinguish it from the Sun version of date.

Do this if not installed:

```
pkg install //solaris/file/gnu-coreutils
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Can you give me an example of how to use it? So I can ask sysadmin to install it...

Comment: On Solaris 11, it will be installed as both `/usr/bin/gdate` and `/usr/gnu/bin/date` so you can choose to use it either by name or by $PATH setting.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Python:

```
from time import *
date1 = strptime("20100909","%Y%m%d")
date2 = strptime("20001010","%Y%m%d")
diff = mktime(date1) - mktime(date2)
print repr(d/86400) + " days"
```

You tagged your question "gawk" but you say "no GNU tools". Gawk has date arithmetic.

Comment: I didn't. Someone edited my post and tagged "gawk"...

Answer (score 2):

**1. Define date1 and date2 in `%j` day of year (001..366) format**

```
user@linux:~$ date1=`date -d 20100909 +%j` 
user@linux:~$ date2=`date -d 20001010 +%j`
```

**2. Calculate the difference with `expr`**

```
user@linux:~$ datediff=`expr $date2 - $date1`
```

**3. So, the answer is 32 days**

```
user@linux:~$ echo $datediff days
32 days
user@linux:~$
```

**... or One-liner Solution**

```
user@linux:~$ echo $(( $(date -d 20001010 +%j) - $(date -d 20100909 +%j) )) days
32 days
user@linux:~$
```

**or**

```
user@linux:~$ expr $(date -d 20001010 +%j) - $(date -d 20100909 +%j)
32
user@linux:~$
```

**or**

```
user@linux:~$ expr `date -d 20001010 +%j` - `date -d 20100909 +%j`
32
user@linux:~$
```

Comment: I like your solution, although it only works for two dates within the same year because `date +%j` returns a number `< 366 days`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the awk [Velour library](//github.com/svnpenn/velour) to return difference in seconds:

```
$ velour -n 'print t_utc(2010, 9, 9) - t_utc(2000, 10, 10)'
312854400
```

Or days:

```
$ velour -n 'print t_secday(t_utc(2010, 9, 9) - t_utc(2000, 10, 10))'
3621
```

Answer (score 0):

With date BSD for macOS :

```
echo "Quelle est la date de début ?"
read DATE_DE_DEBUT
echo "Quelle est la date de fin ?"
read DATE_DE_FIN
ANNEE=$(($(echo $DATE_DE_FIN | awk -F "/" '{print $3}')-$(echo $DATE_DE_DEBUT  | awk -F "/" '{print $3}')))

echo " "

if [[ $ANNEE > 0 ]]; then

for((annee=$ANNEE-1 ; $ANNEE ; annee++))

  do
  #echo $annee  
  for((mois=0 ; 13 - $mois ; mois++))
      do
  #   echo année:$annee mois:$mois
          for((jour=0 ; 32 - $jour ; jour++))
              do
 #             echo année:$annee mois:$mois jour:$jour
           TEST=$(date -Rjf"%d/%m/%Y" -v +"$annee"y -v +"$mois"m -v +"$jour"d $DATE_DE_DEBUT +"%d/%m/%Y")
           if [[ $TEST = $DATE_DE_FIN ]]; then
                  echo "Différence entre le $DATE_DE_DEBUT et le $DATE_DE_FIN";
                  echo "est de :";
                  echo "$annee année(s) $mois mois $jour jour(s)";
             exit 0;
            fi


          done 
  done
  done

 else 
 annee=0
 for((mois=0 ; 13 - $mois ; mois++))
      do
#      echo année:$annee mois:$mois
          for((jour=0 ; 32 - $jour ; jour++))
              do
              #echo année:$annee mois:$mois jour:$jour
              TEST=$(date -Rjf"%d/%m/%Y" -v +"$annee"y -v +"$mois"m -v +"$jour"d $DATE_DE_DEBUT +"%d/%m/%Y")
              if [[ $TEST = $DATE_DE_FIN ]]; then 
                      echo "Différence entre le $DATE_DE_DEBUT et le $DATE_DE_FIN";
                     echo "est de :";
                     echo "$annee année(s) $mois mois $jour jour(s)";
              exit 0;
              fi
              done
      done

fi
```