# How to get elapsed time from two "text based" dates

Tags: shell-script, date

I would like to know if there is a way to calculate the difference between two times in bash.  I have two fields that are extracted from a log file:

Start time:  Feb 12 10:02:10
End time:    Feb 12 10:53:15

What I need is a manual way to get the elapsed time between these 2 dates.  Since the time values are "text based", and not from a date generating command, I don't know if there's a way to do it.  The times are 24 hour based, so hopefully that'll make times spanning midnight easier to handle.  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.
Peter V.

Comment: See here for a number of solutions: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/tool-in-unix-to-subtract-dates

Answer (score 16):

You could use some evil trickery:

```
date -d "Feb 12 10:02:10" +%s
```

will return the number of seconds since the epoch for that date. Combining this with the same command (for the other date) and running through `bc`:

```
echo "$(date -d 'Feb 12 10:53:15' +%s) - $(date -d 'Feb 12 10:02:10' +%s)" | bc
```

or the shell's arithmetic expansion:

```
echo "$(( $(date -d 'Feb 12 10:53:15' +%s) - $(date -d 'Feb 12 10:02:10' +%s) ))"
```

will give you

```
3065
```

the number of seconds between the times. You could probably parse this out with `awk` somehow if you needed to run it more than once.

Comment: great solution.

Comment: Exactly what I would have done.  Looks like it depends on GNU `date` though; see the question Steven D linked to.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind an external helper utility, have a look at my [dateutils](http://hroptatyr.github.com/dateutils).  Above task translates to:

```
ddiff -i '%b %d %H:%M:%S' 'Feb 12 10:02:10' 'Feb 12 10:53:15'
=> 
  3065s
```

where `-i` is used to describe the input date format.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution without `bc`

**1. Convert the dates to Unix time (also known as POSIX time or UNIX Epoch time)**

```
$ date1=$(date -d "Feb 12 10:02:10" +%s)
$ date2=$(date -d "Feb 12 10:53:15" +%s)

$ printf '%s\n' "$date1" "$date2"
1518447730
1518450795
$
```

**2. Calculate the difference between the two dates**

```
$ datediff="$((date2-date1))"
```

**3. You'll get the answer expressed in seconds**

```
$ echo "$datediff"
3065
$
```

**4. Convert it to hours, minutes and seconds format**

```
$ printf '%02dh:%02dm:%02ds\n' $(($datediff/3600)) $(($datediff%3600/60)) $(($datediff%60))
00h:51m:05s
```

or

```
$ TZ=UTC date '+%H:%M:%S' -d"@$datediff"
00:51:05
```

Be alert to the possibility that the result is ≥ 86400 (i.e., 24 hours)
and adjust the format accordingly.