# What's a smart way to count the number of days since X?

Tags: shell-script, date

I started working at my current position since November 17th 2014. I would like to know how many days have run up to now. Any ideas on how to use Linux to come up with a simple and nice solution?

Comment: I ended up doing something similar in a perl script; I used the timelocal() function to get the number of seconds from the epoch to the given date (Nov 17, 2014 for example), then subtracted that from the current epoch-date-in-seconds, then divided by 86400 (seconds in a day). I'm sure someone will come through with a shell-only solution :)

Comment: Time arithmetic has lots of fiddly special cases. While simple things like subtracting UNIX timestamps and dividing by 86,400 will give you an approximate answer, you are better off using a specialized time library that takes into account the special cases, for example Python's `dateutil`.

Comment: Some of the answers in [Quickly calculate date differences](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/quickly-calculate-date-differences) may help here too.

Comment: http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m4bph9tiPe1r9kuhvo1_250.gif

Comment: @msh210 you are banned for life and sentenced to prison for 1 month while serving community as code cleaner for ancient COBOL code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
echo $(( (`date +%s` - `date +%s -d '2014/11/17'`) / 86400 )) days ago
```

Comment: This gets leap seconds wrong.  I mean, that hardly matters *now*, but in [10k years or so](http://longnow.org/about/) the accumulated error could be enough to matter.

Comment: The probability leap seconds will trigger an error in about .000001%. This is negligible compared to the wrong number of days this method will give with locales where daylight saving time is observed: 2% of the cases ...

Comment: @Kevin: If he wants to know how many days he worked somewhere, we can (until further advance in cryogenisation or medicine) not bother too much about this ^^

Comment: @jlliagre: %s is Unix time, which is always UTC, which lacks DST.

Comment: @Kevin the fact `date +%s` works in UTC doesn't change at all the fact the result will be sometimes incorrect in location where DST is in use. "The number of days since X" is timezone dependent, one cannot ignore that fact with pretending to be in UTC.

Comment: Chances are he will be wondering about the number of days employed while idling behind his desk at work. As that's probably not around midnight but somewhere between 8am and 5pm (and `date -d 2014/11/17` gives a timestamp of midnight as there's no time mentioned) DST doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

Well, on the face of it:

```
$ date --date="-239 days"
Mon Nov 17 15:25:40 CET 2014
```

In a script (not very efficient, but... maybe it handles leap seconds? ;) )

```
i=0
result=""
while [ "$result" != "20141117" ]
do
    i=$((i+1))
    result=$(date --date="-$i days" +%Y%m%d)
done
echo "$i" days have passed since "$result"
```

Comment: Even `ago` is understood: `date --date="239 days ago"`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma too bad it's not localized. E.g. `LC_ALL=ru_RU.utf8 date --date="239 дней назад"` gives me the same result as `date --date="239"`.

Comment: @Ruslan indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried python on the command line.

```
$ python -c "import datetime; print datetime.date.today() - datetime.date(2014,11,17)"
246 days, 0:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is example with PHP:

```
<?php
$o1 = date_create('2014-11-17');
$o2 = date_create();
$o3 = date_diff($o2, $o1);
echo 'days: ', $o3->days, "\n";
```

Result:

```
days: 1927
```

https://php.net/function.date-diff