# Accumulate Filename in a Log file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script

I have files with their names as

`ABC_-_123321.20140505_-_161500.CSV`
`ABC_-_654145.20140506_-_135020.CSV`
`String_-_SerialID.`**`Date`**`_-_`**`Time`**`.CSV`

*StartDate, StartTime, EndDate* and  *EndTime* are given as input.

How can I get all **filenames** (or relative paths) having **Date** and **Time** between the given **Date** and **Time** ranges and write those to a Log file using a shell script?

**Date** and **Time** are not the last accessed or modified date/timestamp and there are no whitespaces in filenames.

And I can either take **Date** and **Time** input individually without any seperator between fields, for example
`20140706`
`165030`
or I can take input as
`20140706165030`

Comment: How the date and time relative?

Comment: **Date** and **Time** together would corresponds to a Timestamp.
Is that what u meant ?

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm to do this work:

for each file get the date & make difference the same with given date. Please find the below link for the date difference.

[link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/quickly-calculate-date-differences)

For solaris(unix without GNU date) use this 
 [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/tool-in-unix-to-subtract-dates)

If you want time wise , inside date for loop use loop for time . To get the difference in time you can use following code

```
      time1=14:30
      time2=$( date +%H:%M ) # 16:00
      diff=$(  echo "$time2 - $time1"  | sed 's%:%+(1/60)*%g' | bc -l )
      echo $diff hours
      # outputs 1.5 hours
```

Here `sed` replaces a `:` with a formula to convert to 1/60. Then the time calculation that is made by `bc` ( click [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903239/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-bash-script) for more information).

Note : If the DIFFERENCE is +ve then , log/content can be put designated file otherwise not

Comment: Date difference that would do, but how can I retrieving filename and comparing parts of filename and then storing those filenames who satisfies the conditions into another file.