# How to compare dates (line by line) and get a date range?

Tags: linux, bash, date, file-comparison

I have 2 files with dates, which look like so:

```
# cat file_1
20190105
20171124
# cat file_2
20190112
20171201
```

How do I compare dates (line by line) and get a date range?

For example, something like this:

```
# cat final_file
20190105
...
20190112
20171124
...
20171201
```

Comment: show your efforts

Comment: Are you looking for a range based on year, or month? Could you sort the file and just print the first and last line? 

`$ cat final_file | sort`

Comment: Possibly related: [Store all dates in a given date range into a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141166/65304)

Answer (score 1):

Something like?

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line_a && read -r line_b <&3; do
    seq ${line_a} ${line_b}
    echo "=========="
done < file_1 3<file_2
```

Output will be:

```
20190105
20190106
...
20190112
==========
20171124
20171125
20171126
20171127
...
20171200
20171201
==========
```

Comment: The problem with creating simple sequences is that you will also the values from `20171132` to `20171200`, which are not valid dates.

Answer (score 0):

From the given input and output files it is assumed the data is structed as follow:

```
cat -n FROM_DATE
     1  20190105
     2  20171124
cat -n TO_DATE
     1  20190112
     2  20171201
```

whereby the date has the format of `YYYYmmdd` (and was i.e. [created via `date +%Y%m%d`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401482/yyyy-mm-dd-format-date-in-shell-script)).

To get a better idea about how it looks aggregated, lets [print the two files side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341832/display-two-files-side-by-side).

```
pr -m -J -t FROM_DATE TO_DATE
20190105        20190112
20171124        20171201
```

So it seems the questions is more about "How to expand the range of values which are splitted over two files and have the result aggregated?".

Following the hints from @steeldriver s comment and @Nortole s answer, a possible solution could look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r START_DATE && read -r END_DATE <&3; do

echo $START_DATE

    for (( DATE="${START_DATE}"; DATE != END_DATE; )); do
        DATE="$(date --date="${DATE} + 1 days" +'%Y%m%d')"
        echo $DATE # which will be equals to END_DATE at the end
    done

done < FROM_DATE 3<TO_DATE
```

Running the script will give the expected output:

```
20190105
20190106
20190107
20190108
20190109
20190110
20190111
20190112
20171124
20171125
20171126
20171127
20171128
20171129
20171130
20171201
```