# Subtract two dates using Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, shell-script, date

How can I subtract two dates in epoch format using Shell Scripting.
I want the output in Months, Days, Hours format.
Also It should work even for more than 12 months ( as I came across few which were resetting to 0 months if more than 12)

Comment: Epoch format ? number of second since 1/1/1970 ?

Comment: Yes Archemar... no. of seconds since 1/1/1970.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Tool in UNIX to subtract dates](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1825/12779)

Comment: didn't it depends on starting date ? 29 days from Jan,31 to Mar,1st (and one month), 29 days from July,1 to July,30 and zero month.

Comment: https://github.com/hroptatyr/dateutils is the best bet so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

d1=`date -d 20140929 +%s`
d2=`date -d 20001115 +%s`

date --date=@$(($d1 - $d2)) +'%m months, %d days, %H hours'
```

Output:

```
11 months, 15 days, 02 hours
```

Comment: This resets months count each year

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work.  Here's what I get:
`d1="03/26/2022"`
`d2=$(date +%m/%d/%Y)`
`date --date=@$(($d1 - $d2)) +%m-%d-%H`
`12-31-19`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

d=(60sec 60min 24hours 30days 12month 1000year)
i=0

while [ $1 -ge ${d[i]%%[a-z]*} ]
do
    set -- $(($1/${d[i]%%[a-z]*})) $(($1%${d[i]%%[a-z]*})) ${d[i]##*[0-9]} ${*:2}
    ((i++))
done 
echo $1 ${d[i]##*[0-9]} ${*:2}
```