# UNIX (non-posix) day of year from supplied date?

Tags: solaris, date

I have been looking for an existing solution to obtain the day of year (not the julian date) from an existing date on UNIX platforms.

I am sure it exists but I have yet to find it and am unsure of the math to perform accurate results while accounting for leap years etc.

Comment: UNIX implies POSIX. A Unix compliant is  a POSIX compliant system (but not all POSIX compliant systems are also Unix compliant).

Comment: What do you mean by "the day of year"?  That pretty much means Julian date, assuming you mean the number of days since the beginning of the year.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, Julian date would be a date in the Julian calendar which nobody uses any more. Julian day number would be the number of days since January 1, 4713 BC, proleptic Julian calendar (2457610 just now)

Comment: For better results, you should mention the format of the existing date (timestamp in seconds since 1970-01-01, ISO date 2016-08-09, other?) and the environment you are running in (plain shell or perl, python, Java...)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas My question was directed at the questioner, given "obtain the day of year (not the julian date)" doesn't really make sense, as "the day of the year" usually means just that - the Julian date.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, and I'm saying no, the Julian date for today 2016-08-09 (Gregorian calendar) would be 2016-07-27 (the date in the Julian calendar that for instance Britain dropped for the Gregorian calendar in 1752), and the Julian day number would be 2457610, while the OP presumably wants 222 (the 222nd day of the year in the Gregorian calendar for 2016 starting on January the 1st)

Comment: Unfortunately the term "Julian date" or "Julian day" is often used *incorrectly* to refer to the day of the year. The `date` command and the `strftime()` function use `%j` to refer to the day of the year, and it may have originally stood for Julian, but that's not what it means. Just think of it as a letter that happened to be available.

Comment: See the answer provided as strftime() is not a viable solution in this particular instance. And I did indeed have to implement a 'Julian Date' vs. the 'Julian Day' provided by the GNU %j option with the date command.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answers but it seems that Solaris 10 the math would have to be implemented to achieve this.

I decided to tackle it another way by using bash & bc to calculate the Julian day of year. The formula is described [here](http://quasar.as.utexas.edu/BillInfo/JulianDatesG.html). Original function can be found [here](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2013/05/17/how-to-convert-date-to-julian-day-number-using-shell-script/)

The modified function below can do the conversion then you can compare two dates.

```
function conv_date_to_julian()
{
  local cdate="$(date +%d:%m:%Y)"

  local day="${1:=$(echo ${cdate} | cut -d: -f1)}"
  local month="${2:=$(echo ${cdate} | cut -d: -f2)}"
  local year="${3:=$(echo ${cdate} | cut -d: -f3)}"
  local jdoy

  if [ ${month} -le 2 ]; then
    year=$(( ${year} - 1))
    month=$(( ${month} + 12))
  fi

  jdoy=$(echo "2 - ${year} / 100 + ${year} / 400" | bc)
  jdoy=$(echo "(${jdoy} + 365.25 * (${year} + 4716))/1" | bc) 
  jdoy=$(echo "(${jdoy} + 30.6001 * (${month} + 1))/1" | bc)

  echo $(echo "(${jdoy} + ${day} - 1524.5)" | bc)
}
```

Example usage:

```
[ $(expr $(conv_date_to_julian 31 12 2017) - $(conv_date_to_julian)) -gt 30 ] && echo true
```

Comment: For older versions of Solaris, you can always use `perl`. I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: I don't think making use of higher level interpreted languages such as perl and/or python as a work around to some limitations on older versions of shell scripting is an efficient use of memory &/or resources of the system.

I you look at the amount of memory allocated & number of shared objects loaded on calls to perl you can see just how inefficient it really is.

Ideally I would like to remove the extra calls to 'bc' and replace them with 'expr' which would optimize the above code even more.

Comment: Those `day="$([ ! -x ${1} ] && "${1}" || "$(date +%d)")"` don't make any sense. ITYM something like `eval "$(date +'typeset -i day=${1-%d} month=${2-%m} year=${3-%Y}')"`

Comment: You give very bad advice

Comment: `[ -x "$1" ]` is to test whether a file is executable. If you want to test for a non-empty string, it's `[ -n "$1" ]`, Though here you'd use the `day=${1:-$(date +%d)}` or better still to avoid running several `date` commands (and you might end up running them on separate day (or year) if run at 23:59:59.99), retrieve all the values at once with the `eval` I approach I give above.

Comment: Note that the `function conv_date_to_julian()` syntax , hybrid between the Bourne and Korn syntax is only supported by `zsh`, `bash` and the public domain versions of `ksh`, not the shells available by default on Solaris 10 (Bourne and Korn). Note that if using `zsh`, `zsh` supports floating point arithmetics and builtin time utilities.

Comment: I wonder what the relative costs of forking one copy of `perl` vs. three `date`s and four `bc`s are on Solaris. Though of course that would be reduced by doing the calculations in the shell instead of with `bc`. Do you run it often enough for it to matter anyway? Also, if you just want to compare dates, you could do a string comparison: `[ "2017-12-31" > "2016-08-27" ]`

Comment: And, if you're handling dates that fit in the Unix timestamp range, I think you could just do something like `jday=$(( $(date +%s -d "2016-08-27 UTC") / 86400 + 2440587 )).5`.  (Or just compare the timestamps directly.)

Comment: Also, that example doesn't work, `[` on both Bash and zsh barf on the fractional part.

Comment: `[ ! -z ${1} ]` is a little better in that `-z` it to test for a non-empty string, but again like for `-x`, it works (sometimes) for the wrong reasons. In shells, you need to quote variable expansions, otherwise that's invoking the split+glob operator. So it's `[ ! -z "$1" ]` or `[ -n "$1" ]`. `[ -z $1 ]` returns true when `$1` is empty not because an empty string is passed to `-z`, but because then the test becomes `[ -z ]`, which is a test for whether `-z` itself is a non-empty string.

Comment: @ilkkachu, that would be `[ 2017-12-31 ">" 2016-08-27 ]` as otherwise `>` would be take as a redirection operator by the shell and not passed to `[`, but that would only work for some `[` implementations as that `>` string comparison operator is not standard. You can use `expr` instead portably.

Comment: D'oh, of course the `>` needs escaping.

Answer (score 1):

Your tag says `solaris` so I assume that's the platform you're working on.

If you have a standard install of Solaris 11 then it's likely you have `gdate` installed

On my install:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          15 Aug  3 13:21 /usr/bin/gdate -> ../gnu/bin/date*
```

So you can make use of GNUdate `-d` flag:

eg

```
% gdate +%j
222

% gdate -d "1970/06/23" +%j         
174
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have python installed:

```
python -c 'import datetime; d=datetime.date(2016, 8, 9); print(d.timetuple().tm_yday)'
```

or if you have the date in an environment variable:

```
DATE=2016-08-09
python -c 'import datetime; d=datetime.strptime("'"$DATE"'", "%Y-%m-%d"); print(d.timetuple().tm_yday)'
```

(you have to adapt the `%Y-%m-%d` to be able to parse different formats).

Both give `222` as output.

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris 11 (where `/bin/sh` and `/bin/ksh` are based on `ksh93`):

```
$ /bin/ksh -c 'printf "%(%-j)T\n" 2016-01-01 2016-08-09'
1
222
```

For Solaris 10 and older, you can always use `perl`:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -le '($y,$m,$d)=@ARGV;
                    print strftime "%j", 0,0,0, $d,$m-1,$y-1900
                   ' 2016 8 9
222
```

POSIXly (and so UNIXly as well as UNIX conformance implies POSIX conformance), you could use those POSIX `sh` functions (beware that on Solaris, the POSIX/UNIX `sh` is at `/usr/xpg*/bin/sh`) at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stephane-chazelas/misc-scripts/master/wide_strftime.sh:

```
$ timegm 2016 08 09 && wide_strftime '' "$REPLY" && echo "$T_j"
222
```

(beware that like with the `perl`'s solution, it's 0-padded (1 is 001), `%-j` to remove that padding is not supported (it's supported in recent versions of `perl` but not in the very old 5.8.4 one found on Solaris 10), but you can adapt those functions to remove the padding).

The Julian day number itself is in `$T_J`:

```
$ echo "$T_J"
2457609
```

Comment: /usr/xpg4/bin/sh -c 'printf "%(%-j)T\n" 2016-01-01 2016-08-09' results in:
`(j)T`. Your example only works with ksh93 and that is not POSIX compliant.

Comment: @schily, yes, hence me saying to use `/bin/sh` (now changed to `/bin/ksh`) instead. `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` is a POSIX compliant shell based on `ksh88`, not `ksh93`. In any case, `%(..)T` is not POSIX.

Comment: But on Solaris 10 or before, /bin/sh is the Bourne Shell.

Comment: @schily, yes, hence me saying Solaris 11 :-) (and on Solaris 10, ksh would be based on ksh88, not ksh93). You can get a ksh93 on Solaris 10 as /usr/dt/bin/dtksh but it's in an optional package and IIRC, it's based on a very old version of ksh93 and I'm not sure it would support `printf '%(%j)T'`.

Comment: @schily, confirmed, on Solaris 10, `/usr/dt/bin/dtksh` is based on ksh93d (from 1995) and its `printf` builtin doesn't support `%(...)T`

Answer (score -1):

For reference, a rewrite of [your `conv_date_to_julian`](/a/302750) using Bourne syntax as opposed to `zsh` syntax (so would work with the shells shipped by default on Solaris 10 like the Bourne shell in `/usr/bin/sh`, or POSIX shell in `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` or `/usr/bin/ksh`), to return the Julian day number (the number of days since January 1, 4713 BC, proleptic Julian calendar, not what you asked for) and running fewer commands and with fewer bugs:

```
conv_date_to_julian()
{
  date +"
    d = ${1:-%d}
    m = ${2:-%m}
    y = ${3:-%Y}

    if (m <= 2) {
      m += 12
      y--
    }

    j = 2 - y / 100 + y / 400
    j = (j + 365.25 * (y + 4716)) / 1
    j = (j + 30.6001 * (m + 1)) / 1
    (j + d - 1524.5) / 1" | bc
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that example uses variable declarations available in the global scope which could introduce `bugs` and is not as maintainable as spelling out the variable name(s).

Comment: Yeah, I was referring to the `d`, `m`, `y` & `j` var naming and not using the `local` keyword

Comment: @jas, as ilkkachu said, that's assignment of `bc` variables for that one `bc` invocation, that's not assignment of shell variables (global or otherwise)