# Time difference between two ISO8601 dates with fractional second part

Tags: timestamps, alpine-linux

I receive the following time stamps from Alpine Linux:

```
2017-04-25T07:19:53.946109551Z    
2017-04-25T07:19:53.946155414Z
```

How do I decode them and know how much time has passed between them?

The linked question talks about epoch time while here it's clearly not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tool in UNIX to subtract dates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/tool-in-unix-to-subtract-dates)

Comment: @don_crissti, wrong dup. That one if for non-GNU solutions while I suppose alpine linux is a GNU system. There has do be plenty of duplicates though. See also the nano-second part here which complicates slightly

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - there's a comment by Gilles on that Q and it points to the GNU alternative. It's true that here it's a bit more complicated...

Comment: OP, the linked question _doesn't mention anything about epoch times_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On GNU systems:

```
d1=2017-04-25T07:19:53.946109551Z
d2=2017-04-25T07:19:53.946155414Z
printf '%s - %s\n' "$(date -d "$d2" +%s.%N)" "$(date -d "$d1" +%s.%N)" | bc
```

Would give you the time difference as a floating point number of seconds.

Caveat: the number will be given using period (`.`) as the decimal separator even in locales where it's the comma (`,`) instead.

You could pipe that output to `tr . "$(locale decimal_point)"` to fix it.

Or, with `zsh`, you could do:

```
printf '%.9f\n' $(($(date -d "$d2" +%s.%N) - $(date -d "$d1" +%s.%N)))
```

instead which will give you a number with the correct decimal separator in your locale.

However since then `zsh` uses the `double` number format of your processor, you may find that it gives a different number as numbers like `1493104793.946109551` reach the limit of precision of those numbers. `bc` doesn't have the issue as it uses arbitrary precision.

`zsh` has time parsing capabilities builtin, so one can also write a solution that will work on non-GNU systems like:

```
parse_iso8601_full() {
  local t
  typeset -Fg REPLY
  zmodload zsh/datetime
  TZ=UTC0 strftime -r -s t %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S ${1%.*} &&
    REPLY=$t.${${1%Z}##*.}
}

parse_iso8601_full $d1; t1=$REPLY
parse_iso8601_full $d2; t2=$REPLY
printf '%.9f\n' $((t2 - t1))
```

Comment: In what units is the last part of the number (e.g 946109551) ?

Comment: @Yakov, in those standard time stamp specifications, `53.946109551` is the number of seconds as a floating point number.